# No Primal Feasible Solution, GLPK

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, glpk

I can't figure out what's wrong with this model. I continually get a No primal feasible solution error. It appears the problem is with the Stope_i constraint. I'm thinking there's some misrepresentation of the constraint. Can anyone help?

```
#parameters

param n := 13;
param m := 8;
param k := 2;
param l := 2;
param p:= k-1 ;
param q:= l-1;

#set of items

#set I;
#set J;

set I := {1 .. n} ;
set J := {1 .. m} ;
set P := {1 .. n-p};
set Q := {1 .. m-q};


#parameters


param V{I, J};



# Decision variables
var x{I, J} >= 0, <= 1;
#printf (V[3,1]);

#check:      sum {i in I, j in J} V[i, j] * x[i, j] = 12;
maximize z: sum {f in I, g in J} V[f, g] * x[f, g];

subject to StopeB{g in P, h in Q}:
        sum{i in g .. g+p, j in h..h+q} x[i,j] <= 1;

#subject to Stope_i{g in P, h in Q}:
#        x[g,h] - sum{j in h+1..h+q} x[g,j] = 1;

#subject to Stope_j{g in P, h in Q}:
#        x[g,h] - sum{i in g+1..g+p} x[i,h] = 1;

#subject to Stope_ij{g in P, h in Q}:
#        x[g,h] - sum{i in g+1..g+p, j in h+1..h+q} x[i,j] = 1;

#subject to Stope_im{g in P, h in Q}:
#        x[g,h] - sum{i in g+1..g+p, j in h+l..m-1} x[i,j] = 1;

data;

param V: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 :=
1       -25  -9  14   21 50  13   78  37     
2        14  11  14  17  -43  -30  68  75    
3        2   7   18  -44  -63  4   4   72    
4        -8  4   18   -63  -36  60   41   80    
5       -8   6   18   -28  -27  22    52   55   
6        -8  8   18   -8  3  21  30   19 
7       -4   9   17   18  27  16  -45   -58    
8        26  16  7    21 -22  -30   -38   -53  
9        36  11  6   43   -4  -31  78   105   
10       8   -1   -51   -15   50  12   122    154  
11       4  7   -49  -38  30  15   61   71  
12       30  11  0   20   23  21   29   -43   
13       -2   -11  -59  -22   52   -9   -1   -20  ;

end;
```

Comment: What kind of modeling language is that?

Comment: @mattmilten, It's GLPK.

Answer (score 2):

This is my python code for your model using [PySCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt):

```
from pyscipopt import Model, quicksum

model = Model()

n = 13
m = 8
k = 2
l = 2
p = k-1
q = l-1

I = range(n)
J = range(m)
P = range(n-p)
Q = range(m-q)

x = {}
v = [[-25,-9,14,21,50,13,78,37],
     [14,11,14,17,-43,-30,68,75],
     [2,7,18,-44,-63,4,4,72],
     [-8,4,18,-63,-36,60,41,80],
     [-8,6,18,-28,-27,22,52,55],
     [-8,8,18,-8,3,21,30,19],
     [-4,9,17,18,27,16,-45,-58],
     [26,16,7,21,-22,-30,-38,-53],
     [36,11,6,43,-4,-31,78,105],
     [8,-1,-51,-15,50,12,122,154],
     [4,7,-49,-38,30,15,61,71],
     [30,11,0,20,23,21,29,-43],
     [-2,-11,-59,-22,52,-9,-1,-20]]

for i in I:
    for j in J:
        x[i,j] = model.addVar(vtype = 'BINARY', name = 'x_{}_{}'.format(i,j))

model.setObjective(quicksum([v[i][j] * x[i,j] for i in I for j in J]), sense = 'maximize')

for g in P:
    for h in Q:
        model.addCons(quicksum(x[i,j] for i in range(g,g+p) for j in range(h,h+q)) <= 1)

for g in P:
    for h in Q:
        model.addCons(x[g,h] - quicksum(x[g,j] for j in range(h+1,h+q)) == 1)

for g in P:
    for h in Q:
        model.addCons(x[g,h] - quicksum(x[i,h] for i in range(g+1,g+p)) == 1)

for g in P:
    for h in Q:
        model.addCons(x[g,h] - quicksum(x[i,j] for i in range(g+1,g+p)) == 1)

for g in P:
    for h in Q:
        model.addCons(x[g,h] - quicksum(x[i,j] for i in range(g+1,g+p) for j in range(h+1,m-1)) == 1)

model.optimize()

for i in I:
    print([model.getVal(x[i,j]) for j in J])
```

It returns an optimal solution:

```
SCIP Status        : problem is solved [optimal solution found]
Solving Time (sec) : 0.01
Solving Nodes      : 1
Primal Bound       : +1.40200000000000e+03 (2 solutions)
Dual Bound         : +1.40200000000000e+03
Gap                : 0.00 %
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -0.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -0.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -0.0]
[-0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 1.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0]
```

Comment: First off, thanks a bunch for taking the time out to convert the code to Python, Matt! Could you please share with me what package you installed to do LP in Python? Is it a proprietary one? I'd like to run the code on my side here and see how it works because based on our definition of the model and constraints, the solution presented here is infeasible.

Comment: There might be a typo in my model or in your description. PySCIPOpt would not silently compute an infeasible solution and claim optimality.

Comment: Right, thanks. I'm thinking more about the model still needing to be properly formulated. I'll look into it.